# Creating an array with unique rows and columns

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

How do I create an array with unique rows and columns like this one in python?

```
  [1, 2, 3, 4] 

  [2, 3, 4, 1]

  [4, 1, 2, 3]

  [3, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Does it have to be random, or could you just rotate the row by one place each time?

Comment: Take a look at itertools for the permutations function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import choice

>>> a = list(permutations([1,2,3,4], 4))
>>> total = [choice(a) for i in range(4)]
>>> total
[(3, 4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 4, 3), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
>>> print(*(' '.join(map(str, item)) for item in total), sep='\n')
3 4 1 2
4 1 2 3
2 1 4 3
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with the `itertools.permutations` method:

```
import itertools
a = [1,2,3,4]
list(itertools.permutations(a))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 4, 3), (1, 3, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4, 2), (1, 4, 2, 3), (1, 4, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3, 4), (2, 1, 4, 3), (2, 3, 1, 4), (2, 3, 4, 1), (2, 4, 1, 3), (2, 4, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2, 4), (3, 1, 4, 2), (3, 2, 1, 4), (3, 2, 4, 1), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3, 4, 2, 1), (4, 1, 2, 3), (4, 1, 3, 2), (4, 2, 1, 3), (4, 2, 3, 1), (4, 3, 1, 2), (4, 3, 2, 1)]
```